# Building Netty on Mac OSX Lion under Java 1.6.x

Tags: netty

I'm trying to build The Netty Project on Mac OS X Lion which has Java 1.6.x. (IDE: NetBeans).
Then I get the following error:

```
[enforcer:enforce]
Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion failed with message:
Detected JDK Version: 1.6.0-31 is not in the allowed range [1.7.0,).
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If Netty only requires java 1.5 or above, I'm looking for a way to enable compiling under java 1.6.x.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you download the source for the stable release, or an unstable release? The download page says, "JDK 1.5 or above is all that you need to run Netty. However, the unstable releases might require a newer JDK version."

Comment: I downloaded the stable version available at site. netty-3.4.2.Final-dist.tar.bz2 (Stable, 27-Apr-2012)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have java7 to build but only require java5 to run. This is because we enable/disable some features at runtime depending on the java version.

See also [1].

[1] https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4e528c10fae3abaa932e751c831aa48a23645744/README.md

Comment: Thanks. Since I'm using mac, I'd have to wait for official java 7 for mac or use previous netty release till then.

Comment: Java7 for osx is out. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html. Im also using osx

Comment: BTW, you can run netty 3.4.x also with java5, just not compile it.

Comment: I was waiting for the update from Apple. But now I'm using java 7 on my mac thanks to you.